# error access of undefined event

Tags: actionscript-3

i cant seem to go back to the first frame after the game over screen.
i get the error message Scene 1, 1119: Access of possibly undefined property Event through a reference with static type Class in frame 2 is it because i don't have a classset up in frame 1.

```
import flash.events.Event;
stop();
var isRight:Boolean=false
var isLeft:Boolean=false
var isUp:Boolean=false
var isDown:Boolean=false
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, downKey);
function downKey(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
if(event.keyCode==39)
{
isRight=true
}
if(event.keyCode==37)
{
isLeft=true
}
if(event.keyCode==38)
{
isUp=true
}
if(event.keyCode==40)
{
isDown=true
}
}
```

ect...and the next frame code to go back to the previous one is

```
import flash.events.Event;
restart.addEventListener(Mouse.Event.MOUSE_UP,click)
function click(e:MouseEvent)
{
gotoAndStop(1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you accidentally wrote `Mouse.Event.MOUSE_UP` instead of `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP` in your addEventListener function